# How can I use Python to convert multiple columns in the same row to another row?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file which has multiple title names as columns within the same row where the data is given, I need to sort the data and convert the column names to rows and assign it to the data under the "column names"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtxdP.png)

My expected output is for it to turn out like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsfSO.png)

Im not sure how to start with this, can someone help out here?

Edit: sorry about the img description, im new here

Comment: Welcome! To make helping you easier, please go through [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and adjust your question accordingly :-)

Comment: [Please don't post images of data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check rows with names of new column values by column `b` testing missing values, replace non matched `a` column values to missing values by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and forward filling missing values, last filter with inverted mask and columns `a,c` in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')

#sample data
print (df)
      a    b                c
0    IT  NaN              NaN
1  User  1.0  user1@gmail.com
2  Data  NaN              NaN
3  User  1.0  user5@gmail.com
4  User  1.0  user2@gmail.com

m = df['c'].isna()
df['a'] = df['a'].where(m).ffill()

df = df.loc[~m, ['a','c']]
print (df)
      a                c
1    IT  user1@gmail.com
3  Data  user5@gmail.com
4  Data  user2@gmail.com
```